# Probabilities between two distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, scipy

I have two histograms of score distributions, and I have fitted a probability distribution to both. The probability distribution functions are thus known.

How can I find out the probability of distribution A having higher score than distribution B?

All kinds of solutions are welcome but SciPy-based would be optimal.

Here's an example:
[image: Example image]

Comment: (1) Please note that the distributions are *not* known: they are *estimated* from the data.  Thus it may be worth bearing in mind that the computed probability is itself an estimate.  Among other things, this raises the possibility of estimating the probability in different ways, such as by computing the difference in rank sums of the two datasets.  (Information about this is given in most discussions of the [Wilxocon Rank Sum test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Related_test_statistics)). (2) Do you know that these two datasets are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have the distributions already. For example, if I knew I had a beta distribution I could,

```
def sample_distributions(dataA,dataB):

    samplesA = beta.rvs(alpha_0, beta_0, size=10000)

    samplesB = beta.rvs(alpha_1, beta_1, size=10000)
    return samplesA, samplesB

samplesA, samplesB = sample_distributions(dataA,dataB)
```

Then to find the probability,

```
(samplesA > samplesB).mean()
```